# Optional chaining operator weird behaviour

Tags: typescript

I am experiencing some weird behaviour in TypeScript (v4.6.2). Why does (a) work but (b) and (c) don't?

```
const a: string[] | null = []
if (a?.length > 1) {
    console.log(1)
}

const b = [] as (string[] | null)
if (b?.length > 1) {
    console.log(1)
}

const c: string[] | null = [] as (string[] | null)
if (c?.length > 1) {
    console.log(1)
}
```

[image]

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgLhtATgSzAcwNoF0YA%20MYArgDZkwC8MeAUGgGYwAUcA-AHRkCmWUACxgA%20GAEYAlDADedGPJihIIXtxCYWkugF86dJdBgAjarXxwIrVBhz4ipChIbMWRrr35DRkmXIUGVHjUNLV19cENgJGssPEJickoaOIsrKHRYuwTHZ1Zgdz5MQRFxKVkFRQjA4M0nbSA)

Comment: what's interesting is that `b ? b.length > 1 : undefined` also works fine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the following:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#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-pQaHhPJt2Ntg3tLodgD02Bw-ZGKMCAILZcJpRwuA1GrypfLWYqlMrAIkyeqCJqtDqdSl0uuMllsmAQznebl8sACoV+OSiiUyuXAxXKsCq+AaqT27W6-WG+AXU2pUKWzvWnt2xZjGQTKYzd3cACSyBImEwMiW4C0c-CWZ1UBSKEgzcgKTgcgQdAFwDI4i0npg2J6PYABylwALJATIyY6LoPphmc-pIgA3HiRZlIBuggeBkHQZ8pbljAlSVDAAAMHRktWdrcEMNG0XR9EMTAAB6LFMVRrAAKpZkiKgVqA6rnsA2wGsYwRqOa6gyFEZAkHkWiojIAAehgoOe3j6haJHsc+6SZvJwjguyAa8QCIIaG8qJajq6B6oEUhoEmQzcOqUh6KIfz2FAshlooyoLmaEBFEMGFYRQEGYVBMGxr6EYBtptgkLAqJQEYJiiNADmUGmYgSNI8imfYjjOPp8koCQf7gHIYIFNp3xkAowgRFoqkQOQzwwIkkjYukUnqrJ+aBBaqJkGCqTqjAABeqQgNpGBYm+2bztJ5UdV16QAAbEko63QpIokpQag2aDAUToLE8TaXqpnqg+YB5GgTVkLBcyoeUIUyKBYU4VFABkP1vZBn1kOF9i4XotRliSFYUZRTmsIxCP0axyMo6jaNsXDvDHR8IRdhgo1PTASkqFAogWcoHIgBgUCXaCpSyDAmA5BoEKJOIpkM44gTFc2apk4EOPPXa71AyDkWfNF8E7C9QA)

```ts
const a: string[] | null = []
a // string[]
// TS has narrowed this to the array type in the union
// because you assigned an array to the variable after the type annotation

if (a?.length > 1) { // ok
  console.log(1)
}

const b = [] as (string[] | null)
b // string[] | null
// You asserted that the array could be null,
// so it is now possibly null in the type system

if (b?.length > 1) {
//  ~~~~~~~~~
// Object is possibly 'undefined'.(2532)
// TS won't allow comparison of a number to undefined
  console.log(1)
}

const c: string[] | null = [] as (string[] | null)
c // string[] | null
// Another case of assertion

if (c?.length > 1) {
//  ~~~~~~~~~
// Object is possibly 'undefined'.(2532)
// TS won't allow comparison of a number to undefined
  console.log(1)
}

// I suggest one of these patterns instead:
declare const maybeNullMaybeArray: string[] | null;

if ((maybeNullMaybeArray?.length ?? 0) > 1) {
  //                             ^^^^
  // Use nullish coalescing operator to evaluate the expression to 0
  // in the case that it is nullish, so that the comparison will
  // always be between two numbers

  maybeNullMaybeArray // string[] | null
  // but the type is still not narrowed, because the true condition
  // could have resulted from the evaluation to the literal zero
  // instead of a value from the `length` property on the variable
  // so, alternatively:
}

if (maybeNullMaybeArray && (maybeNullMaybeArray.length > 1)) {
  //                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  // The array definitely exists at this point
  // so if we got this far, we can use it as an array:

  maybeNullMaybeArray // string[]
}
```

See:

- [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) in the TS handbook
- [optional chaining (`?.`) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) on MDN
- [nullish coalescing (`??`) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) on MDN

Answer (score 1):

Case A works because the compiler is smart enough to see that `const a` is actually `[]` and not `null`, although your explicit type declaration says something different.

In case b and c you're casting the value, telling the compiler that your variable might be `null`. In that case `b?.length` might resolve to `undefined`. And `undefined > 1` is not a valid comparison.

Answer (score 0):

In case A the assignment happens after the type has been declared, so typescript is able to figure out that `a` is actually a `string[]`. Therefore you don't even need the optional chaining operator there and can just use:

```
if (a.length > 1) {
    console.log(1)
}
```

In the other cases, you first assign and then cast to a type, so typescript considers the type to be `string[] | null`. The expression `b?.length` returns `undefined` for null values, so you end up with a comparison `undefined > 1` which is invalid. To fix this, you should rewrite the condition as:

```
if (b && b.length > 1) {
    console.log(1)
}
```

Here we make sure that b is not null before accessing the `length` property and doing the comparison.